# Why does the "X open review tasks" indicator show, even though there aren't any posts to review?

Tags: discussion, bug, review-queues

I've noticed this happening a lot recently; I'll be going through my favourite tags, looking at interesting posts, flagging/editing bad ones, etc, then when I refresh the page the open review count indicator decides to show up (I say that because it's been appearing and disappearing quite frequently over the past couple of weeks).

[image]

So I click it, and then it bring me to the "First posts" review queue, which is empty.

[image]

Then I go back to my favourite tags, and it disappears again. So I'm guessing this is a bug, right?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'd have to say this is because there are 700+ review tasks associated with [c#] at any given moment, but *most* of them are in /review/close and therefore you're not eligible to review them. I'll see if m0sa & Geoff have any clever ideas here...

Comment: @Shog9 Oh, I thought that number was for the reviews that were actually available for my current rep, didn't realise it was the *total* count. Is this maybe due to the datacenter move or something?

Comment: This has been answered here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266078/827168. The count number is cached for a short period, so it might be not accurate at times