# Review page does not work as before

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues

I do not seem to be able to get to the review tab right now. I am always getting the error below when clicking on the review button. Does it work for others? What am I doing wrong?

> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site.
>
> It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault.
>
> Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.
>
> Yes, we do look at every error. We even try to fix some of them.
>
> It’s not strictly necessary, but if you’d like to give us additional information about this error, do so at our feedback site, http://meta.stackoverflow.com.

===================== Edit =====================

The review page sort of (*) works again, although it may be useful to leave the thread around due to the cheat sheet.

- the page does load now, thanks go to Shog9 and his crew, but unfortunately, the caching now creates some off numbers, so the displayed number became unreliable.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but going to the individual URLs are fine, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts

Comment: I believe it's http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete if I'm not wrong.

Comment: At the same time though, it's seriously improving review quality. Why don't we remove the review button permanently?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I know were you are coming from...

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong - the message even says `It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault.`.

Comment: @sevenseacat: well, the message could be wrong, and I could be doing something wrong, too, simultaneously. IMHO, it is better not to start blaming others if you do not yet know what is going on.

Comment: I see `1 Late Answers` but when I click to review it, it  is not showing anything, again with I click on review link, it shows me `1 Late Answers`, but there are not Late Answers :(

Comment: Yes, looks like as soon as I post this comment, the developer read it and solve the problem. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've done some rework to marry the aggressive caching implemented last night (which was definitely needed) with some other dynamically cached review question information that was already available. In English, this should hopefully maintain the current cached efficiency of the `/review` page while offering significantly more accurate review counts for the queues. It will be live in the next production release (meta: > `2014.7.18.2381`, network: > `2014.7.18.1715`). Thanks for bringing this up!

Comment: Don't thank me until it goes live and works as expected. :P

Comment: @FinalContest this is now live; cache duration has also been lowered to three minutes, contingent on database pain.

Comment: Would it be possible to revert the whole change? It seems to cause lots of duplicates, and the contributors do not seem to be particularly happy about it. I personally find it regressive, that is, it has brought one not unnoticable disadvantage without advantages, at least thus far.

Comment: [This issue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266066/review-seems-stuck-with-stale-numbers-today?lq=1) still occurs, not yet fixed.

Comment: Yes it still occurs. For me, both pending review count in the top bar and review page are almost always incorrect. I just gained the review privilege but this problem doesn't make me happy to use it. If it's not corrected in any ways, I'm pretty sure in the long time I won't do review task anymore because it make me loose time ("hey look ! here's a review pending for you" *click* "we don't have anything for you !" WHAT ?!). Also, I understand the caching problem, but (no offense in the following) is it that **that** hard to *at least* decrement the counter whenever an user do a review task ?

Answer (score 13):

Yes, they are broken. In the meantime, cheat links!

- Close votes: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close
- Reopen votes: https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen
- Suggested Edits: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits
- Low Quality Posts: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts
- First Posts: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts
- Late Answers: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers
- Tools for you <s>lucky</s> poor 10kers: https://stackoverflow.com/tools

Answer (score 11):

The page was trying to calculate accurate counts per-queue for every user who visited that page, taking into account the individual rules of each queue in order to count only tasks each reviewer could actually review.

This was getting really, really slow. Tonight, it passed the point where the system just gave up and killed it.

Fortunately, our hardworking dev team was able to jump in and revive it, by drastically simplifying the logic and adding some much-needed caching. The page should load much faster now, although some counts may be slightly off at times.

Comment: Unfortunately, the caching makes that page pretty useless now - you have to check manually whether there is really something in the queues.

Comment: @WladimirPalant: well, it does not make the page "pretty useless" as it is still useful a container,  but such caching is indeed too much for the usability of the real numbers, I agree.

Comment: @FinalContest It does make the *number* useless. Why even display a number, if it's never going to tell you whether there are actually reviews available or not? Why not just say "click to see if there are any reviews available"? If every time I visit the page, it tells me that there are >0 reviews available, and there never are, I'm just going to stop paying attention to it anyway.

Comment: So, you finally fell victim to a distributed denial-of-service attack? If many users would load the page at the same time before, it would overload the systems and cause it to crash.