# /review seems stuck with stale numbers today

Tags: bug, review-queues

I have never experienced this problem before in all my time of reviewing.  I can't believe that caching on my browser (Firefox) is behaving differently today.  What I am seeing is stale numbers in each of the 6 categories.  For example, it will tell me that there are 7 suggested edits when the queue is in fact empty.  I do a few reviews, return to the page and I see the exact same 6 numbers.  A few minutes later I will finally see updated numbers but it seems like instead of realtime numbers, there seems to be a sampling going on.  Why the delayed update of numbers today?

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266000/review-queues-do-not-work (Shog's answer and following comments)

Comment: Ok, my question is clearly a duplicate, but just couldn't find it because the title was too different.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, it seems the issue you're talking about is caused by the fix for the linked question

Comment: Isn't that info cached, and thus not always up-to-date?

Comment: @Deduplicator possibly but it's not usually this stale.

Comment: @Jack: no, because *things changed*, see Shog's answer on the linked post. Yes, this *is* a duplicate because Shog's answer answers this question too.

Comment: This is due to some new caching. I'm checking to see if we can do anything further to improve the situation. The current caching is for 5-10 minutes on the `/review` page which could definitely make things look a little stale.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I understood  Deduplicator's comment as saying that it was always cached and therefore not up to date... (I'm aware of Shog's answer). I disagree about it being a duplicate though, a dupe means the question is a dupe not that the same answer answers both.

Comment: Yep, I'm noticing this as well - I supposedly have 8 reviews right now, and have for several minutes, which I don't actually have.

Comment: @Haney: hey, so I guestimated the numbers correctly! :-P

Comment: @Jack: we mark posts as duplicates because the *answers* on the other question can help the OP. Not because the question is exactly the same.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Not exactly the same as long as they are essentially the same question, but I don't think that just because one answer works for both question that it makes them automatically a duplicate (though it's usually a good indicator that they are indeed dupes). In this case the linked question is why the review is down, and this question is why the numbers are off. It's true that both came about from the same actions but that doesn't mean the question is the same.

Comment: This issue still occurs, not yet fixed.

Answer (score 5):

For the longest time, the review main page showed you fresh numbers; each time the page was loaded you got the latest and greatest review counts *just for you*.

Calculating those numbers is costly, and yesterday [things blew up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266000/review-queues-do-not-work). Things are working again now, but the decision was made that providing you with fresh numbers is no longer doable.

As a result, the numbers on the main review page are now cached. That means that for up to 5 or 10 minutes or so, you'll see a number that is *not fresh*. Each time your specific number of pending reviews is calculated, the numbers are stored in a cache and are reused until the cache expires.

See [Shog's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266018):

> Fortunately, our hardworking dev team was able to jump in and revive it, by drastically simplifying the logic and **adding some much-needed caching**. The page should load much faster now, although **some counts may be slightly off at times**.

Comment: As I posted in that thread - why bother displaying a number, if it's never going to tell you whether there are actually reviews available or not? Why not just say "click to see if there are any reviews available"? If every time I visit the page, it tells me that there are >0 reviews available, and there never are, I'm just going to stop paying attention to it anyway. I'd rather no number than a number always incorrectly telling me there were items in the queue.

Comment: @neminem: but it doesn't do that. It looks if there are numbers *for you*; if not, it'll calculate your personal review counts, then cache those. For the next 5 minutes or so, it just won't recalculate those. Come back in 5 or 10 minutes, and **fresh numbers are produced**.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The problem with that is that when you come back, the numbers for you could be stale again by another couple of minutes and you _still_ have nothing to review but are told you do. At the same time, it's better that the issue was fixed, even if the caching fix infuriates people.