# Posts pending in Review queue, but doesn't appear on review page when clicked

Tags: discussion, bug, review-queues

I'm facing this issue since last 12-15 days.

When in click on "review" tab on main navigation bar, then page comes up with come pending review post count as show below.

[image: Review Count]

But, if I click on "First Posts" link to start reviewing it, It often shows me *"There are no items for you to review."*.

[image]

I understand that there are many reviewers currently reviewing posts so, *I may not get allocated any post to review.*, But If I click again on "review" tab on main navigation bar, It keeps showing me same number of posts for pending review.

Is it only for me, that *"There are no items for **you** to review."*, Or others also facing same issue?

Please let me know, are there any limitations given for specific tagged questions review like, the person who is brilliant in some `PHP` tag and with `-ve`  rank in `Java` tag *Can not review question/answer tagged with `Java`?*

Or is it a bug?

**EDIT**

- However I tried clearing cookies and re-logging to site.

Comment: They recently introduced caching of the review counts, see [Shog and Haney's answers here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266000/review-page-does-not-work-as-before). See also: [/review seems stuck with stale numbers today](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266066/review-seems-stuck-with-stale-numbers-today)