# Review Queue shows posts but on click it says queue is clear

Tags: bug

Upon a refresh, the review queue shows there are posts to be reviewed [image]

But when I click it, it says it is empty[image]

This happens quite often and I am unsure why it is showing that there are posts in the queue if it is empty.

Comment: [Posts pending in Review queue, but doesn't appear on review page when clicked](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266367/posts-pending-in-review-queue-but-doesnt-appear-on-review-page-when-clicked)

Comment: Better directly to [Review page does not work as before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266000/review-page-does-not-work-as-before)

Comment: @Deduplicator that's why I did not vote to close as duplicate :-)