# Why does it sometimes say that I can review posts when I really can't?

Tags: support, review-queues

When I'm heading to my review window I sometimes get this thing happening. First:

[image]

So I think "great, 9 reviews. Much fun!". But when I click the link it gives me this:
[image]

Why is that? (I don't think that the reviews have been answered before I manage to click the button since I can sometimes head back and it still says the same number of posts).

Comment: Caching (and this is a dupe).

Comment: thanks, I'll look on that question @MartijnPieters

Comment: I wrote what I think is a more [informative answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266072) to another dupe.