# Review cache indicator / timer

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

### User story

The well-intentioned reviewer:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

1 millisecond later:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

### Problem statement

The queue lengths advertised on the [review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review) are now cached because recalculating them for every page click was too costly [[1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266018/119775),[2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266072/119775)].

The upshot is that visiting the review page has become a rather frustrating experience. The numbers there are perpetually outdated. You think you're clicking on a queue where there's work to be done, but as often as not, the queue then tells you, go away, I'm empty. This is quite discouraging to reviewers (at least this reviewer).

Is a set of perpetually outdated numbers *really* the most useful piece of information we can supply to reviewers?

### Feature request

Two non-mutually-exclusive options, in addition to (or instead) those queue length numbers:

#### Option 1: a non-cached boolean

Would a boolean for each queue be less expensive to retrieve for every page load than the actual number of posts? (Sorry if this is naïve; I don't know the first thing about databases.)

> There is currently something to review in...
>
> Close Votes      **TRUE, ALWAYS SO VERY TRUE**
>
> Suggested Edits  **TRUE**
>
> Reopen Votes     **TRUE**
>
> First Posts      **FALSE**
>
> Late Answers      **FALSE**
>
> Low Quality Posts      **FALSE**

#### Option 2: a timer

The reviewer can decide what to do based on how recent the numbers are.

> Queue status last updated **10 seconds ago**.
>
> Next update in **8 minutes**.

Ok, the queue lengths shown are probably realistic.

> Queue status last updated **7 minutes ago**.
>
> Next update in **5 seconds**.

Hmm, I'm not going to waste my time clicking 4-5 different queues; go straight to the close queue, which is always full. Or maybe wait 5 seconds.

Comment: -1, not enough Grendizer attacks in user story.

Comment: Or (and no idea about performance cost), an "empty" "low" "medium" "high" compared to daily norms.

Comment: I would be a huge fan of Option 2. Having some sort of indication of how old the numbers are would be a huge help. Granted, you can go to the individual queue's "recent reviews" page to get the live up-to-date number, but that seems to be a bit out of the way and slow to load.

Comment: [Happens to me all the time](http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/tumblr_ldpevo8ROs1qagfhx.gif)

Comment: I think any kind of counter on how many items are in the queue are doomed to fail because of the inherently high concurrency of reviews. Just remove the damn thing, it will never be correct.

Comment: @ivarni: Or reduce granularity, an order of magnitude of the number of items in the queue (10s, 100s, 1000s, 10000s) could be cached easily and not be outdated as fast.

Comment: On the plus side, as you can see the previous reviewers, you can rage at them instead for beating you to it!

Comment: I think they should just say "probably not empty" or "definitely not empty".

Comment: If I could award a bonus to this question I would.   "What??? Noooo!   Not againnnnn!!!