# First Posts / Late answers - 'This queue has been cleared!'

Tags: bug, review-queues, new-users, late-answers

Very often I get this message. It certainly looks like a bug:

> "This queue has been cleared! If you're looking for more to review,
>   view all review queues.  Want to get back to the questions? Return to
>   the Stack Overflow homepage."

I see this message after clicking over

> "First Posts"

Or

> "Late Answers"

Both being bigger than zero.

Have you experienced this before?

Comment: Probably caching. There are never that many posts in those queues, so it's easy for them to get cleared out.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276031/review-cache-indicator-timer?cb=1