# Numbers in review queues' summary are always inacurate. Why don't we get rid of them?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

What is the reason, behind presenting any numbers in [review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/review), if they're **always** inaccurate?

Seriously! I don't know, if this is only me or others has the same, but for me it always goes like this:

1. *First Posts* and *Late Answers* queues shows some numbers and when I click any of them I nearly always hit the "*This queue has been cleared!*" wall. And even if I sometimes, really rarely, don't hit that wall, then these numbers are always too high -- showing, that I have more than one item to review, when actually after first review... bang! Again, "the wall".
2. *Suggested Edits* queue is very often inaccurate the opposite way, i.e. summary claims, that I have zero items to review in this queue and when I click it, I always actually have something to review. There were many times, when I did entire 20 reviews day limit to this queue, when summary was claiming, that I have nothing to do in it.
3. *Low Quality Posts* queue has the lowest rate of false numbers. But, even here there are differences between number at summary and actual number of review items available.

I have a review privileges for a half a year or more and today is the **first** day, when one of the queues was actually correct. For the first time, *Suggested Edits* queue was showing `0` in the summary and for the first time I hit the wall, when I clicked it.

I know, I know... the answer is (as always)... the cache, right?

But, seriously, guys. If these numbers are so incredibly and so often misaligned with the reality, then why don't you simple hide them from the review queues' summary. They seems to be pretty useless there.

Comment: Or, at worst, keep them with a timestamp of when they were last updated.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276031/review-cache-indicator-timer

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com ... Also I think there is quite *some* iterations of this here on meta..

Comment: @Kendra I'd even go so far and count that as duplicate..

Comment: Agree with the sentiments, but yeah, that's a dupe.

Comment: Wait till you get to 3K and can start enjoying the numbers of the CVQ...

Comment: @Vogel612 The only reason I didn't is that feature request didn't specify removing the indicator, just trying to improve it. Therefore, I wasn't entirely sure it was correct. I'll leave that to 3kers.

Comment: @all Yet another question about this feature request (or rather: feature request removal), yet another closed as duplicate and yet nothing is done. Sure, sure... SE devs ARE listening to us, right? Wasn't that something about, that we don't mark as duplicate a feature request that hasn't been implemented after certain period of time? Wasn't that we keep them open, to "remind" devs, that we want this and that this wasn't implemented yet? Because, you know... SE devs ARE listening to us, so we need to keep reminding them this, right...