# Why does the First Posts Queue sometimes have a dramatic spike in post count?

Tags: support, review-queues, new-users

I've been reviewing for a few months, and I've never seen the [First Posts queue](//stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) with more than 15 posts in it at once (and even that was only because of the [new caching](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266000/review-page-does-not-work-as-before/266018#266018)). Recently, there were ~165 posts awaiting review:

[image: First Posts Review Queue on Saturday, August 9, 2014 at 12:11:03 UTC]

Before I did my 20 reviews, it was over 200.

Is there some change I missed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[According to Shog9](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2294283#2294283), the weekly scheduled tasks that run on all sites to delete old content just ran after [being delayed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237493/is-the-30-day-roomba-broken) a few days.

The deletion of old first posts suddenly makes some users' second posts their first posts, ushering them into the queue. The delay exaggerated this effect, causing a large number of posts to be sent to the queue.

This happens regularly, but it is easy to miss because reviewers handle posts quite quickly and the First Posts queue only requires one reviewer to take action to complete a review.

As of this posting, only 5 need review now and 195 have been reviewed today (which, in UTC, has been half an hour).