# Why number of Suggested Edits showing different?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, review-queues

I have clicked on the button given in the title bar for giving review for suggested edit. but, I could not see any pending review for suggested edit in https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits page. BTW, in the review page it was showing me 0 suggested edit pending. I have refreshed page many time with Ctrl+F5. but, the button in the title bar showing me 25 pending suggested edit.

[image]

This screen shot has taken after 2 hours of posting this question. So, it happens every time.
[image]

Comment: Then why catch doesn't clear on Ctrl+F5. it happens many time with me. @Justcode

Comment: even we refresh the page it doesn't get changed. if u click on that button in the title bar it won't show the any review pending..

Comment: yeah its possible @iStimple but, i think they are missing something to implement in SO Title Suggested Edit button. it should be updated same as review page.. I hope it will be done shortly.

Comment: @iStimple, 21 for me now. I think it was good yesterday?

Comment: This has been answered here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266078/827168. The count number is cached for a short period, so it might be not accurate at times

Comment: @pomeh agree with you but after pressing Ctrl+F5 the Review number given in title bar is getting changed but, actually im not getting any review in Suggested Edit. If the the issue is in cache then why it is getting changed on page refresh?

Comment: for me, the number doesn't get updated every time when I press Ctrl+F5. Sometimes it's updated, sometimes not, so for me it's not related

Comment: @pomeh actully it will be updated when someone gives the review as *iStimple* has [said](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270145/why-number-of-suggested-edits-showing-different?noredirect=1#comment86767_270145) in his first comment

Comment: yes it may be, so it's not *directly* related to Ctrl+F5

Comment: yeah @pomeh might be, possible the problem may be in review count filtration or something else. I think only *Haney* can have the answer. So, i should stop thinking about it.

Comment: Something must has been changed over last 24 hours, the number is keep changing with only one thing in common - _there is nothing to review._

Comment: @pomeh (& Shell): The value is cached **on the server**, so CTRL + F5 won't fix it. However, given that this is out of sync so badly, & for so long, I wouldn't be surprised if something *other* than caching is to blame here...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A fix has been deployed.  We are now [doing a lot more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor/238039#238039) to make sure that each person reviewing suggested edits has a good opportunity to accurately review them.

It's a bit like ticketmaster, or any type of reservation system. When you visit a suggested edit review task it's now "checked out" to you for that time - the counter previously didn't reflect the amount of "checked out" tasks.

Comment: Is it really a bug?

Comment: What do I need to do to see the changes? I mean it still shows 25 with no item for me to review.

Comment: @Bolu *"[there's another level of caching happening here, I'll get to the bottom of it shortly - another large change is coming through at the moment](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2356900#2356900)"*

Comment: Have you disabled the status of number of pending suggested edit on the title bar. bcause, i can see 13 pending suggested edit in review page and also i can give review those pending items. but, i couldn't see that pending status on the title bar at the left of the review button. its just blank. I think it must be caching issue.

Comment: It was temporarily set to only show at 20 items in the queue.  It's now shown when there are 10 or more @Shell

Comment: I'm seeing this behaviour today the suggested edits queue shows 0 but when I click there are edits there waiting.

Comment: Still there. Writers.se, the counter showed 4, I got 3 to review, afterwards the counter shows 3, with the queue cleared.

Comment: FYI this is still happening