# Problem with suggested edits count

Tags: support, bug, review-queues

I am experiencing a problem with the suggested edits count next to the review link on the top bar.

In that past, the number would occasionally appear when there were posts awaiting review, over the past few days however, the number always appears even when there are no posts awaiting review.  It was 15 earlier, now it stands at 38.

Has the review system been changed recently?

Comment: Seeing this too, was about to post a question about it.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270145/why-number-of-suggested-edits-showing-different ("A fix has been deployed.")