# Show only "available" review count

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues

I've already found question about ["*number of suggested edits being different*"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270145/why-number-of-suggested-edits-showing-different) in site header and actual counts in queue.

Shouldn't the number in the header (164 in the screenshot bellow) reflect **only** the number of reviews *available to me*?

[image: Review count]

In this particular screenshot the number should be *~164-88* in my opinion. This way I have no way of knowing (without leaving current page) whether there are other queues "*full*" or just the ones I cannot participate in at that moment.

Assuming current counter works like this:

```
types = (Low Quality, First Posts, ...)
result = sum(approx_review_count(type) for type in types)
```

And I think it should work like this:

```
result = 0
types = (Low Quality, First Posts, ...)
for type in types:
    if user_has_votes_remaining(user, type): # 
        result += approx_review_count(type)
```

where `approx_review_count` returns cached number of reviews for given type and `user_has_votes_remaining` returns `false` if user has no "votes" left for given type (sees *come back in xxx hours* message)

Comment: While you're waiting for this to be fixed, do some Close Vote reviews...

Comment: I think this [answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218489/158100) explains why this isn't updated real-time.

Comment: @rene that's why I've posted link to "number is different". I understand why it's not calculated in realtime and so on. But remembering in session variable or cookie or whatever list of the queues that you cannot participate in at the current moment and leave those out of the sum should be possible (server would just need to return `27;8;1;1;88` instead of `164` and "*client*" would do the calculation in one simple loop).

Comment: Sure, I have some extra reading material for you: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223460/why-are-only-suggested-edits-quantities-shown-in-the-toolbar

Comment: @rene although the links are interesting I am not sure how they are related to my question. Maybe I didn't make myself clear in the question. I'm not expecting more "realtime" view or anything. I just want a glimpse on how many reviews are there available to me (btw: fair point with close votes), whether its 0-20, 20-70, 70+ would do for me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the main reason is the required overhead is a lot to calculate everyone's *individual* remaining review votes minus the queue total.
As individual remaining review votes can change as users do reviews, scripts would have to calculate this for every user, on every page load.

---

If it displayed what we can do individually, how would we know what the total queue is?
Then, would anyone place any urgency or importance on them?
I think a lot of people seeing "20" would think "someone else can sort them" (badge hunters etc aside).
Whereas showing 164 will give users a sense of urgency, and so the reviews will be actioned.

As it is, showing the actual queue total, just do reviews as you naturally would, a few, or 20.  I don't see why knowing what "you" can do would change anything useful.

That said, I sincerely think it should be changed so it doesn't show anything up there when you have used up all your review votes for the day.
Which is essentially the resolve to your issue, as if you just showed what you can do, as you suggested, you would see "0", which is potentially misleading, but definitely pointless.

Comment: Somewhere in the system they already have separated counters for *closing vote queue* and the rest (it's not showed in the counter). So I think it's logical to assume that at some point it has all the counters available (Close: 11k, Low quality: 10, First Post: 15...) and just sum them to display to users. `counter = sum(reviews_count(queue_type) for queue_type in queue_types if not used_all_votes(current_user, queue_type))`. It seem quite easy to implement to me. I've added pseudocode for implementation.

Comment: It probably is *easy to implement* but simple to code doesn't negate overhead. What you describe may just be actioned on the review page only, not on every single page we view throughout the site.

Comment: And exactly as you said "*sense of urgency*". When I see 50+ reviews "waiting" I have higher tendency to review than if there were just 10. But clicking on review button just to find out that there's full *Low Quality Posts* queue and others are empty is just *frustrating* (is that the right word? annoying is probably more accurate). And overhead... Sending array of 5 integers instead of 1 integer doesn't seem to be that much big of a deal... I guess only guys who implement it know.