# Why there is such a huge discrepancy between total posts awaiting for review and real number of posts waiting

Tags: discussion, review-queues

The picture will help with understanding what exactly I am referring to.

As you see there are 800 posts awaiting for review, but in fact, there is definitely less than 200. I do understand that some things are cached, so they are not real time. But in such a case the top number is absolutely useless. What is the point of showing a number which not even close to a real number?

So back to the question. Why do we have such a big difference between real posts that need attention and the number I see in my top bar?

[image]

Comment: @PatrickHofman this is what I am thinking about. But in such a case the top number is absolutely useless. What is the point of showing a number which not even close to a real number.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278330/show-only-available-review-count

Comment: @PeterJ at least there the number is 2 times of. Here it is more than 4 :-). Anyway, thanks for a related question.

Comment: @Matt at that point of time wildly out was 50. Do not even know what to say about 600.

Comment: @PatrickHofman *Shall we blame the cache?* [hmm I'm not sure](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)