# Bug in the "Help and Improvement" review - Count is incorrect

Tags: bug, review-queues, help-improvement

I think there is a bug in the **Help and Improvement** review queue. For example, if the question count is 5, and I start reviewing and just quickly skip questions, I'm usually done after 2 or 3, not after 5. So my feeling here is that the count is too high.

That's not what I observed with the other review queues. The count on them seems to be correct.

[image: screenshot]

**I think this is a bug.**

Comment: Those counts are never correct due to [caching](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266018/578411)

Comment: Posts are reviewed by others before you can get to them.

Comment: @rene Then why do I not experience this with other rewiew queues?
approxiblue Like I said, this also happens when you just quickly skip all of them.

Comment: @bytecode77 I dunno....

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Not caching. This would also affect other review queues, but it doesn't.

The difference between **Help and Improvement** and any other review queue is that once you are in the review, it is locked exclusively to you until you are finished.

Other review queues are usually reviewed by more than one user and are not locked. Due to the lock, review items are quickly taken and then released.

Comment: Any umm post saying this? I swear other review queues it also locks?

Answer (score 1):

This is a combination of [caching](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266018/578411) and other people reviewing before you do them.

Yes, you may be "quickly skipping" them, but there are of 1000s of people reviewing.

Comment: Why is it so hard to believe me? I didn't see this happen in any other review queue.

Comment: @bytecode77 Why so hard to believe? Because it's more likely that caching is happening, especially considering the evidence linked...? And it could be that the others are updated faster / change less often?

Comment: No caching. See my answer below.